# How to install a multipart python program on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, wxwidgets, pyserial

Finally making a legitimate mac installer for my product. I've made a successful Windows installer with Inno installer. I'm not sure how to do this in Mac.

This must happen: 
-Python is installed
-Wx is Installed
-Py Serial is installed 
-Program is copied
-Shortcut is made. 
I was doing this with Bash scripts before, but my customers having been complaining about those. Perhaps X-code package maker is the solution? I know the recommended method is "just copy files" but these libraries must be installed somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am using Fink for installing packages, I usually just download the .tar.gz file from the source and install it from terminal inside the unzipped folder containing the install.py file. Terminal command:

```
sudo python ./setup.py install
```

If you would like, I can show you how to set up and use Fink, which is another easy way to install packages / libraries.

Comment: He wants a deployable installer. If I had to guess, it needs to have a GUI.

Comment: Thanks, thought I would give my little input that I know. Still working towards 15 points so I can cast my vote on posts.

Comment: Fink's a useful solution for package management for console apps and UNIX programs. I'm sure someone will need it eventually...

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) will make a self-contained application bundle out of your Python scripts, making it real easy to employ the 'just copy files' installation process. The libraries you need are bundled into the app bundle itself, so they don't need to be installed systemwide.

Also check out [Optimizing for Mac OS X](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X) from the wxPython wiki; it gives good tips on using py2app and other useful information on building a Mac-friendly Python application.

---

On OS X, programs are generally installed through one of three ways: the Mac App Store, a package installer (.pkg/.mpkg), or a copyable application bundle on a disk image (.app in a .dmg). Each has its strengths and weaknesses.

The Mac App Store requires that you subscribe to Apple's restrictions and requirements, and may be a good choice for apps expecting wider distribution (though, nowadays, it can be a good way to reach that wider audience easily). Copyable application bundles are by far the simplest installation method pre-App Store, and still remain one of the more popular ways to install programs. Finally, an Installer package is a user-friendly way to install more complex programs requiring more than a simple application bundle (e.g. system services, files in particular directories, system-dependent components, advanced installation logic, etc.). I should note, though, that do exist complex applications which ship as application bundles and perform the bulk of their 'installation' at first run.

My experience with the Mac App Store is limited, so I won't talk about it. You can find more details at the [official website](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/distribution.html).

Python is quite amenable to being shipped as an application bundle. You can use [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) to automatically create an application bundle for the program, and then drop that bundle into a Mac disk image (.dmg) using Disk Utility to create a complete installation package. This doesn't support making shortcuts, but on OS X it is much more usual for users to just drop the app into /Applications and make the necessary dock shortcut themselves if they want.

The next way is to make a metapackage (.mpkg) which will be installed using the OS X standard Installer utility. This is in line with what users will expect from a Mac application. IIRC, both Mac Python and wxPython ship as .pkg already, which should make it easier to integrate them into a metapackage. `bdist_mpkg` can help with making packages for pyserial and your own program, which can be added to the metapackage. Finally, using the third-party `dockutil` script, you can automatically add a dock shortcut. Note, however, that installers generally do not add shortcuts to the dock; it is more usual to have a program installed to the `/Applications` directory.`